# PHP preg_match list links

Tags: php, preg-match

First of all, my php skills ain't good at all. I'm trying to list all links that looks like this:

```
<a href="..." class="bokstav">...</a>
```

from a site:

```
file_get_contents('.....');
```

How can I find these links with preg_match or such?

/tb

Comment: Use DomDocument instead (use the loadHTML() method).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's easier with phpQuery or [QueryPath](http://querypath.org/):

```
$html = file_get_contents($url);
$qp = qp($html);
foreach ($qp->find("a.bokstav") as $a) {
    print $a->attr("href");
}
```

If you want to try it with preg_match, look at http://www.regular-expressions.info/examples.html or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89718/is-there-anything-like-regexbuddy-in-the-open-source-world to get started.